# unrecognized modifier P in zsh script

Tags: zsh

I'm running this zsh script but I get the following error message:

```
./executable: unrecognized modifier `P'
```

The code of the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/zsh

setopt no_unset err_exit pipe_fail

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    cat <<EOF
Usage: ${0:t} something1 something2 ..
EOF
    exit 1
fi

foobar=${argv[1]:P}
```

I understand this error has to do with the foobar assignment but I cannot find anywhere where this `P` is used for, nor why it is useful. Any ideas?

Comment: [Zsh modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)

Comment: I see. Thanks. But why isn't it recognized?/

Comment: Possibly your zsh is old? Check the version and see if the docs for that version include :P. I answered with a workaround.

Comment: Is it possible that it will work in Linux zsh but not on macOS?

Comment: The `:P` modifier is relatively new, introduced in version 5.3. You might want to check what version of Zsh you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try replacing with

```
foobar=$(readlink -f ${argv[1]})
```

That will only work if the file exists, which :P does not require.

Answer (score 0):

The `:P` modifier was added in Zsh **version 5.3**, and thus will be unavailable in older versions. A similar, but not quite identical approach would be to **use the `:A` modifier instead**.

From `zshexpn(1)`:

**Modifier `:a`**

> Turn a file name into an absolute path:  prepends the current directory, if necessary; remove '.' path segments; and remove '..' path segments and the segments that immediately precede them.

**Modifier `:A`**

> Turn a file name into an absolute path as the 'a' modifier does, and then pass the result through the realpath(3) library function to resolve symbolic links.
>
> Note: on systems that do not have a realpath(3) library function, symbolic links are not resolved, so on those systems 'a' and 'A' are equivalent.
>
> Note: foo:A and realpath(foo) are different on some inputs.  For realpath(foo) semantics, see the `P` modifier.

**Modifier `:P`**

> Turn  a  file  name into an absolute path, like realpath(3).  The resulting path will be absolute, have neither '.' nor '..' components, and refer to the same directory entry as the input filename.
>
> Unlike realpath(3), non-existent trailing components are permitted and preserved.

I omitted some of the more extraneous details, so be sure to check the man page; the "History Expansion" section, subsection "Modifiers".